# Undefined Error message while running Facebook API

Tags: javascript, dom-events

While running below code getting Undefined message, can some one help?

Javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('artdeco-button__text');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++)
 {inputs[i].click(); }
```

Comment: javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('artdeco-button__text');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++)
 {inputs[i].click(); }

Answer (score 0):

idk what is the exact error message that you get.
but first, make sure if it returns HTMLCollection for var inputs.
secondly, use something like Array.from(inputs) to make `inputs` array so it's iterable and you can now do Array.from(input)[1].click(), I guess
hope this helps